# Email Regex falsely accepts comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a `RegExp` for validating single email address. It validates `,` (comma) which it shouldn't.

Following is my regex:

`^[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$`

It also works as expected on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QyE4QL/2).

Expected Output:

- `test@email.com` (**valid**)
- `test@email.com,test` (**invalid**)

Is my regex wrong or there is some other issue?

Here's my snippet:

```js
var regex = new RegExp("^[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$");

console.log(regex.test("test@email.com"))
console.log(regex.test("test@email.com,test"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're not escaping your regex. Just replace `\` with `\\`:

```js
var regex = new RegExp("^[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\\'?]+(\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})|([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$");

console.log(regex.test("test@email.com"))
console.log(regex.test("test@email.com,test"))
```

`\.` becomes just `.`, inside the resulting in memory string. And that means any char is matched, instead of only a true dot. So need to escape twice, one for the string encoding, and one for the regex escaping sequence.

In Regex101 you write the Regex, not a JavaScript representation of the Regex. So you don't need the escaping required by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! I want to know why not escaping it made it accept comma.

Comment: Alternatively, if you instead create your `regex` using the `var regex = /<EXP>/;` syntax, escaping your `\\` is not needed. But both work

Comment: It's not a problem about regex, it's a problem about strings. Write on your console `console.log("This backslash is not escaped \! But this is \\.")`

Comment: The `/<EXP>/` is really useful in these cases, as by m_callens.

Comment: Finally: `\.` becomes just `.`, inside the resulting in memory string. And that means any char is matched, instead of only a true dot. So need to escape twice, one for the string encoding, and one for the regex escaping sequence.

Comment: @A.Chiesa can you put this last explanation in answer? Also, any idea why was it working on regex101?

Comment: I believe any regex you enter on regex101 is automatically treated as a regex not as a string that has to be converted to a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the regex used in `type="email"` from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.value.multiple) and  here a link to [Email Address Regular Expression](http://emailregex.com/) That 99.99% Works.

Code example:

```js
var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

console.log(regex.test('test@email.com'));
console.log(regex.test('test@email.com,test'));
```